# How to delete bookmarked SQL requests and export templates in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Title says it all. The [current doc on bookmarks](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faqbookmark) doesn't say a word about it.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not but it may be worth your time to read some of the posts just in case it helps you get closer to a solution that will work in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474454/how-to-access-a-bookmarked-query-in-phpmyadmin. I don't use phpmyadmin or else I'd test myself but I wanted to share that with you in case you want to read over, test, etc. I know it is not about "deleting" but maybe it gets you closer to a working solution.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT (*slaps forehead*) Of course it's in another schema, so you can edit it with phpMyAdmin... Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it is actually quite simple once you are reminded that all this is likely kept in another shema of the DB, that you can also tinker with phpMyAdmin. So the answer is:

- open the `phpmyadmin.pma__bookmarks` table
- double-click the fields you want to edit or click the Delete button to remove the entry.

The same applies to export templates (table `pma__export_templates`).